# NextJS with next-i18next produces error Text content did not match

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I think Ive set up next-i18next exactly as their docs specify, but I'm receiving the error "Text content did not match. Server: "Testing ZH HANT" Client: "Testing EN" - the frontend only ever displays the English text. I must have missed something, but for the life of me I can't see what.

Here are the files:

next-18next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en-US', 'zh-hant', 'zh-hans'],
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
        localeDetection: false
    },
};
```

next.config.js:

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ['mydomain.com'],
    },
    i18n,
    target: 'serverless'
}
```

_app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import Head from "next/head";
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, mainMenu, footerMenu }) {
  return(
      <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

Article.js:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

export default function Article(props){

    const node = props.node;
    const { t } = useTranslation(['common']);
return(
        <div>{t('Testing')}</div>
)}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const { alias } = context.params;
    const lang = context.locale;
    const node = await restGet(`/endpoint?_format=json&slug=${alias.join('/')}&lang=${lang}`);
    const globals = await getGlobals(lang);
    const props = {
        ...{node: node},
        ...globals,
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(lang, ['common']))
    };

    return {
        props,
        revalidate: 5
    }
}
```

public/locales/zh-hant/common.json:

```
{
  "Testing": "Testing ZH HANS"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when while I was using several language files. On the client I was reading one file `about.json`:

```js
const { t } = useTranslation(["about"])
```

But I forgot to load this translation file in `getStaticProps`, so I had to add it here too:

```js
props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "about"])),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the `localePath` in your i18next config file?

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  ...
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that zh-hant should actually be zh-Hant - it's always the details :)